# Call script (program name) over textfile

Tags: linux, bash, command, config

I have a `bash` script, that opens a second program. For this, I used this command:

`programname -parameter -parameter`

But the program name can be different. For example `"program1"`, `"program2"`, `"programABC"`. The name of this program is saved in a file called '`config`' and can be changed there (i don't want to use parameters here, i need this configfile).

For example, when i need "`program2`" I do

`echo "program2" > config`

The parameters in my script are always the same - no matter which program I use.

Now, my script should get the first line from my "`config`" file and attach the two parameters (first given code).

I tried something like

`cat config | -parameter -parameter`

But this won't work.

Comment: Does the `config` file only have the program name to be run and no other content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding [useless-use-of-cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat), try

```
"$(<config)" -parameter -parameter
```

This will work as you need, only if the `config` file has only the program name to be run.

Comment: This is the solution. But where is the difference between `cat` and your answer (or with the answer below with `"$(cat config)"` )? I see that this is much shorter because of the 'missing' pipes, but do i get any other benefits?

Comment: @ipo: AFAIK, a better shell utilization in terms of not using any non-native shell tools, but using the built-in features. A fewer CPU cycles maybe, but not sure on this minimal file input.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
"$(cat config)" -parameter -parameter
```